# convert php array to json treeview

Tags: php, json, treeview

i have a json like this:(this is for treeview jquery plugin which load treeview by ajax)

```
[
{
    "text": "1. Pre Lunch (120 min)",
    "expanded": true,
    "classes": "important",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "text": "1.1 The State of the Powerdome (30 min)"
        },
         {
            "text": "1.2 The Future of jQuery (30 min)"
        },
         {
            "text": "1.2 jQuery UI - A step to richnessy (60 min)"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "text": "2. Lunch  (60 min)"
},
{
    "text": "3. After Lunch  (120+ min)",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "text": "3.1 jQuery Calendar Success Story (20 min)"
        },
         {
            "text": "3.2 jQuery and Ruby Web Frameworks (20 min)"
        },
         {
            "text": "3.3 Hey, I Can Do That! (20 min)"
        },
         {
            "text": "3.4 Taconite and Form (20 min)"
        },
         {
            "text": "3.5 Server-side JavaScript with jQuery and AOLserver (20 min)"
        },
         {
            "text": "3.6 The Onion: How to add features without adding features (20 min)",
            "id": "36",
            "hasChildren": true
        },
         {
            "text": "3.7 Visualizations with JavaScript and Canvas (20 min)"
        },
         {
            "text": "3.8 ActiveDOM (20 min)"
        },
         {
            "text": "3.8 Growing jQuery (20 min)"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I want to write a **php array** which returns a json like this. Please help me.

I tried several ways to do it ,but I cannot do it.

Comment: Is your problem to find the correct array structure in PHP, or how to convert a PHP array to that JSON structure?

Comment: same data in php: http://codepad.org/MHFHwBTs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) PHP function

Comment: hi and thank you . bat i want write a php array which  when echo this array with json_encode. this json like json in my question